# Android single line TextView without the dots

Tags: android, textview, truncate

Is it possible to have a single line `TextView` that cuts off at the nearest pixel and does not add three dots?

Comment: You got any solution for this?

Answer (score 27):

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_ivew"
    style="@style/Text.Title"
    singleLine="false"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:lines="1"
    android:text="text"></TextView>
```

Comment: according to Eclipse's documentation singleLine is "* Deprecated: 
 This attribute is deprecated and is replaced by the textMultiLine 
 flag in the inputType attribute. Use caution when altering existing layouts, as the default value...." i used it without and works fine on android 2.1 :)

Comment: `inputType` on `TextView`? Isn't that or EditText?

Comment: Didn't work with me, text still shows ellipsis (left cell pushes right cell to the right so text in right cell shows ellipses).

Comment: setting android:ellipsize="none" in XML is enough.

Answer (score 5):

You should just be able to set the android:ellipsize property to false on your TextView in xml.

Comment: or android:ellipsize="none" in XML.